# Can't click in Safari nor interact with menus

Tags: safari, bug

I am stuck with Safari :

- when I open it, I can't click anywhere (I just here the "bong" sound),
- most of menu items are grayed (including `Quit Safari`),
- none of keyboard shortcut will work,

When I force quit and re-launch, I am stuck in the same state.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to quit Safari in a proper way (without force quit):

1. Open Preferences (using keyboard shortcut <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>)
2. Now `Quit Safari` is enabled : just press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

Now, when relaunching Safari, it works correctly.